# Oracle Oc4j 10i JNDI Datasource lookup problem

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle10g

I am facing a JNDI Datasource lookup problem in Oracle OC4JAS 10i deployment. This problem occurs only in quartz scheduler job. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "-userThreads" switch in the command which starts OC4J.

For eg : 
java -jar oc4j.jar -userThreads